# Unable to get PHPSESSID to work in Ubuntu 18.04 with Redis and Flask-Session

Tags: python-3.x, ubuntu, redis, flask-session

I know this question might be a bit obscure, and might not even be in the right stack exchange. So I'm going to start here.

I'm running `flask` and `flask-session` with `redis`

My app config is setting the `SESSION_TYPE` to 'redis'

I'm also using `u-msgpack-python` for compatibility with PHP vs `pickle` in `flask_session/session.py` (manually changed in the dist-packages), but this seems to have no bearing on whether it works or not.

When running this configuration on Debian 9 or Ubuntu 16.04 everything works just fine. (Also Python 3.4, or 3.5, and PHP 7.0, and Apache or Nginx (both work))

However, when I run the exact same code base on Ubuntu 18.04 with Python 3.6 it will not hold the session.

The session cookie name is `PHPSESSID` and key prefix is `PHPSESSID:`

But.. when I change the cookie name to something like `MYSESSID` it all works and holds the session on Ubuntu 18.04. As soon as I change it bask to `PHPSESSID`, it fails to hold the session.

I've monitored the Redis server and I can see the session come in with data, so I know it's communicating properly.

Other info:

Running: Nginx 1.14.0, Python 3.6, Ubuntu 18.04, PHP 7.2

Any direction or insight will be helpful. Perhaps it's the PHP version?

*Feel free to change tags as necessary, or ask for more info and I will provide as I can. I have full root access to the server.*